# How to install libcouchbase-1.1.0.dp8 on mac?

Tags: couchbase

I am trying to install the gem couchbase-1.2.0.dp6.gem. But on installing it asks for libcouchbase-1.1.0dp8.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing couchbase-1.2.0.dp6.gem:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/ms/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for libcouchbase_get_num_replicas() in -lcouchbase... no
You should install libcouchbase >= 1.1.0dp8. See http://www.couchbase.com/develop/ for more details
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir
--ruby=/Users/mohammad.salim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
--with-libcouchbase-dir
--without-libcouchbase-dir
--with-libcouchbase-include
--without-libcouchbase-include=${libcouchbase-dir}/include
--with-libcouchbase-lib
--without-libcouchbase-lib=${libcouchbase-dir}/lib
--with-couchbaselib
--without-couchbaselib


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/couchbase-1.2.0.dp6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ms/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/couchbase-1.2.0.dp6/ext/couchbase_ext/gem_make.out
```

I have installed libcouchbase-1.1.0dp4. But how can I install 1.1.0dp8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using edge versions, I recommend you install them using:

For libcouchbase (most recent is 2.0.0beta3)

```
$ brew install https://github.com/couchbase/homebrew/raw/preview/Library/Formula/libcouchbase.rb
```

For ruby gem (most recent is 1.2.0.z.beta4)

```
$ gem install couchbase --pre
```

Comment: I was able to install on Mac. How can it be installed on Ubuntu?

Comment: sudo wget -O/etc/apt/sources.list.d/couchbase.list http://packages.couchbase.com/preview/ubuntu/couchbase-ubuntu1110.list;

wget -O- http://packages.couchbase.com/ubuntu/couchbase.key | sudo apt-key add -;

sudo apt-get update;

sudo apt-get install libcouchbase2 libcouchbase-dev